# Сложить значение нескольких полей в MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть 8 полей, (price1, price2, price3, ... price8). Как сложить все поля и записать это значение в поле price. Думал реализовать на Php, но можно ли реализовать это в Mysql. Если price1!=0 то все складываем и записываем в price.

Comment: `update tab set price=price1+price2+...price8 where price1!=0`. А вообще странная у вас структура с 8 однотипными полями. это нарушает первую нормальную форму и скорее всего имеет смысл нормализовать таблицу и развернуть в вертикаль

Answer (score -2):

Написать mysql триггер для этой таблицы. Который на событиях insert/update будет записывать в поле price сумму необходимых полей, если выполняется условие price1!=0

Comment: Вредный совет. Например, в случае, когда изменения в эту таблицу вносятся триггером.